# 403 ошибка на собственном сервере виртуальной машины при работе с PHP

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Установил виртуальную машину: скачал конфигурацию с сайта Puphpet.com
Запустил vagrant up, затем vagrant ssh
Поместил файлы своего сайта \projects\example4.com\www
При нахождении в этой директории файла index.html - работает сайт,
удаляю index.html, оставляю index.php - ОШИБКА 403

Вот конфиг сайта в /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

[image: Вот конфиг сайта в /etc/nginx/sites-enabled]

Конфиг nginx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое каталога:

[image: Содержимое каталога:]

Список процессов: 
[image: Список процессов:]

Вот что в логах:

2018/12/03 11:31:00 [error] 23457#23457: *18 directory index of "/var/www/example4.com/www/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.56.1, server: example4.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example4.com"

Занимаюсь по книге Котерова "PHP в подлиннике"

Думаю ответ кроется в том ,что нужно запустить пулы своих сайтов

Comment: пользователь от имени которого запущен nginx не имеет прав на чтение файлов в /var/www/example4.com/www

Comment: есть ли возможность это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R < user > < directory >
```